# How can I implement a brake in my child's 12v car?

Tags: dc-motor, braking

I recently got my child a 12v ride on car.  The car's internal control does not have a brake, but there is a parent remote control which has an emergency brake button.  This button seems to hold the motors from spinning, so the car stops abruptly.

In contrast, when driving the car from its internal controls and letting off the pedal, the car only slowly decelerates and continues rolling, making stopping with precision difficult.

How might the remote's emergency brake button work, and how might I put the same into the car's internal control?

Unfortunately the controls are exclusive, i.e. only the remote or internal controls work at one time, so my first idea, which was to simply fix the remote into the car to allow for the button to be avaialable, wouldn't work.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to insert a relay and brake resistors between the motor driver circuit and the motor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fubTqM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This requires much more effort - you'll have to take close pictures of the guts of the motor controller, wiring diagram (reverse engineered if need be), motor connections, battery connections, pedal controller and its guts, etc. Otherwise it's unanswerable.

Comment: This is not asking about a repair, but how to engineer a **braking** function. It does need further information, and in such cases I think questions should remain active for 24 hours or so, allowing the OP time to provide what is required. And the "break" should be corrected to "brake".

Comment: you could add another brake relay to the left of the existing one  and use higher resistances, (or if you want to get fancy  a carbon pile variable resistor with two taps that is compressed by the brake pedal)